# Problems installing optisystem

Tags: installation, trial

I try to install optisystem 7 or 10 on my computer after the 7 days evaluation finished,  so i made windows formatting and install new windows although the program can't be run and each time says that the license is not available ,can any one help me to solve that problem

Comment: Maybe you need a license for the program?

Comment: yes the program need license but it should give me 7 day free for evaluation is there any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your PC has been registered in their database as having been used to run a trial version before, and hence no further trial period is granted for that particular PC. You may also have been sent a trial code to your email address, so that you can not active a new trial using the same email address. I guess you can try to install the product on a different machine or get a new trial code sent to a different email address.

In essence the software is probably working as expected with regards to the trial period, but you didn't get to finish your testing phase within the time limit.